# Memory for amd ryzen 5 2600X ryzen 7 1800X

Tags: pc, desktop, memory, compatibility

I am looking for a DDR4-3200mhz 16Gb (2x8) memory under 170$ that will work at full speed or over 3000 mhz out of the box without overclocking with ryzen 5 2600X or ryzen 7 1800X and gigabyte X470 aorus ultra gaming mobo or any equal mobo

Please if anyone can help and i don't mind changing mobo

Right now i am considering G skill Flare X but its 250$ and a many say that AMD compatible is just a marketing thing.Did it work for anyone out of the box at full speed ?And is there any other cheaper ram ?

Comment: Why do you need memory at that speed? I'm not contesting that there are performance gains to be had with faster memory on Ryzen, but [it's often not worth the price.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_Yt4vSZKVk)

Answer (score 1):

That mobo will support up to 2933Mhz out o' the box, which is about right for 3000Mhz RAM (it's just more honest about what 3kMhz looks like in the math).

AMD compatible is really just a marketing thing, in that AMD specifically tested models using that memory to get the speeds they're reporting, and have confirmed it works with Ryzen's RAM-scaling features.  It is more like an endorsement than anything else. Anything 288-pin and DDR4 should do the job.  High-end memory exists mostly for those who plan to overclock that memory. G.Skill makes amazing RAM and I've been using them to obtain ridiculous overclocks on RAM since my old Athlon X2, but if you're planning to run stock speeds, they're overkill.

Corsair is a great mid-to-high range product that can be obtained inexpensively by comparison.   [This Corsair Vengeance kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0134EW7G8) costs $100 less and will likely get you the results you want. Also, IIRC, Corsair's warranty extends to even if you overclock it later.   It did when I used them on my first i7.

Comment: Thank you very much. But i found G skill 3200Mhz ram at the same price as the memory you mentioned https://pcpartpicker.com/product/Nqp323/gskill-memory-f43200c16d16gvrb   Will it be better to get the 3200Mhz kit with msi B350 tomahawk mobo (because it's on the memory support list of that mobo and its not on the support list of gigabyte X470 ultra gaming) or any other mobo with good VRM and durability that have this ram on its memory support list and just enable XMP ? (I have never done any overclocking but maybe i will do basic overcklocking in the future)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i want to build a pc that handles rendering, video editing, 3D animation, gaming and streaming and that is the reason why i chose amd over intel although i think that  intel is the safest choice regarding durability and memory

Comment: Memory support lists that are company and model specific are mostly there because the memory manufacturer donated RAM to test the equipment during QA in exchange for the recommendation appearing on the list.  As long as your RAM fits the right module, type, and pin count configuration, any should do the job. That's a good price on Ripjaws. 

As far as what you're describing, AMD usually gives you more power out of the box for those applications, while Intel provides more stability out of the box overall.  You get more for the money with AMD usually, but my i7's have outlasted my AMD stuff.